# How to output last non empty line of multiple .csv files to spreadsheet (using bash)?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have multiple text files stored in a directory. My goal is to output the last non empty line (in excel) + the file name.

I have a shell file (script.sh).
That implements the following code:

```
filename=$1
sed '/^\s*$/d'
echo $filename `tail -1 $filename`
```

I have tried the following:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash ./script.sh {} \; | xargs -L1 |
```

Comment: Pipe to `sed '/^\s*$/d'` to remove blank lines then get last line with `tail -n1`?

Comment: Tried it. Still no output.

Comment: `sed '/^\s*$/d' TEST_FILE.txt | tail -n1` works great in my terminal. If you put it in `script.sh` with "$1" instead of TEST_FILE.txt then `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash ./script.sh {} \;` works great too :/